# WSL2 startup trying to connect port 6443 on localhost

Tags: wsl-2

I installed K3S on WSL2 and use systemd to turn on and off k3s

The way I set up K3S referenced this tutorial:

https://boxofcables.dev/deploying-rancher-on-k3s-on-wsl2/

I disabled k3s with the following command:

```
systemctl disable k3s
```

becuase I want to turn it on only when I needed it.

But when I turned on WSL. It was giving me this message:

```
The connection to the server 127.0.0.1:6443 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?
```

I don't have anything related "k3s" or "kubectl" inside my /etc/init.d and .bashrc files.

Any ideas how can I fix this?

Thanks!